# Connect VisualSVN to Softether VPN by Certificate?

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn, softether-vpn

I am using Softether VPN, VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN to commit and update my projects. The project repositories are in a seperate server.
I configure visualSVN like this:
[image]

And this is in SoftetherVPN

[image]

[image]

Both are using the same certificate. But when I try to update solution from my device, it shows difference certificate so the validation is failed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Both are using the same certificate.

No, most likely they (VisualSVN Server and your VPN/Dynamic DNS) are not using the same certificate.

The certificate used by VisualSVN Server for HTTPS is shown on the **Certificate** tab, and you need to configure this certificate in VisualSVN Server, not your VPN / Dynamic DNS software. Instructions for configuring the TLS/SSL certificate in VisualSVN Server are given in the article [KB134: Configuring SSL Certificates for VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00134/).

Comment: I can checkout the solution in the same machine. But I cannot checkout from other machine. It will shows different certificate than I have in VisualSVN.

Answer (score 0):

SoftEther-VPN server provides tunneling to supported client-protocols.

Once you connect to SoftEther-VPN server, if said server is configured to allow LAN, then your local Apps can access other Apps running on remote VPN server's LAN.

However, VisualSVN does not seem to be using a supported client-protocol, hence you need to first connect with a normal SoftEther client-app, then use VisualSVN with `127.0.0.1` (localhost) instead of `test.softether.net`.